# How to create a function in Python that takes a float value and returns a text

Tags: python

I have to create a function in Python that must receive two float values ​​(lat, long),
and with that it must return a string with the names of the Earth's hemispheres
(south/north and east/west).

Function call and return examples:

```
determinesHemispheres(20.33456,9.23223)
#returns the string 'Northern and Eastern Hemispheres' 
determinesHemispheres(89.312234,-22.33345)
#returns the string 'Northern and Western Hemispheres' 
determinesHemispheres(-22.3345,-44.13255)
#returns the string 'Southern and Western Hemispheres'
```

Could anyone give me an idea on how to do this?

Comment: What did you try? Add some code for us to see and help you.

Comment: You understand that the sign of latitude and longitude relates to the hemisphere?

Comment: @PeterWood the sign is included in the input to the function as far as I can tell

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341), as well as [ask] more generally.

Answer (score 3):

```py
def determineHemispheres(lat, lon):
    latitudinal = "Northern" if lat >= 0 else "Southern"
    longitudinal = "Eastern" if lon >= 0 else "Western"
    return f"{latitudinal} and {longitudinal} Hemispheres"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip... my end result for a Python beginner in this activity was...

```
def determinaHemisferio(x,y):
   if (x)>0 and (y)>0:
      return ('Hemisferio norte e oriental')
   elif (x)<0 and (y)>0:
      return ('Hemisferio norte e ocidental')
   elif (x)<0 and (y)<0:
      return ('Hemisferio sul ocidental')
```

Comment: What about northeast? What if `x=0` or `y=0`?